# Creating Histogram from describe() data

Tags: python, histogram

How would I create a histogram directly from the mean samples generated by the describe() function on my data file?  I appreciate the help.

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to pull that certain row of mean data from the describe() function to generate a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

**I create a simple dataframe to simulate your data.**

```
etfgroups = pd.DataFrame(data={
'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
'b': [5, 5, 9, 4, 5],
'c': [99, 29, 39, 49, 59],

})
```

You can pull the `mean` data by:

```
 mean = etfgroups.describe().loc['mean']

 print(mean)
```

You will get:

```
a     3.0
b     5.6
c    55.0
```

If you want to specify one element:

```
mean = etfgroups.describe().loc['mean'][0]
print(mean)
```

Result:

```
3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

to calculate the mean for each column in the DataFrame is to use the mean() function directly on the DataFrame.
**Here's an  approach to do this:**

```
import pandas as pd

etfgroups = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'b': [5, 5, 9, 4, 5],
    'c': [99, 29, 39, 49, 59],
})


mean = etfgroups.mean()


print(mean)


mean_a = mean['a']
print(mean_a)
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]